# Ursprung der Verwendung des Wortes "unbedingt" im Deutschen

Tags: etymology

Das deutsche Wort *unbedingt* heißt soviel wie "absolut", "auf jeden Fall".

In anderen Sprachen (in denen ich das beurteilen kann -- Englisch, Französisch, Spanisch) wird die Negation des Wortes "bedingt" nicht im gleichen Sinne verwendet. Während etwa Ausdrücke wie *certainly*, *absolutely* im Englischen gebräuchlich sind, sagt niemand *unconditionally* um einen hohen Grad der Sicherheit, der Notwendigkeit oder der Zustimmung auszudrücken.

Was ist der Ursprung dieser speziellen Verwendung des Wortes *unbedingt* im Deutschen?

Comment: Das englische "unconditionally" entspricht dem deutschen "vorbehaltlos" oder "bedingungslos". Das sind keine Synonyme für "unbedingt". Das Wort "unbedingt" wird allerdings im mathematischen Sprachgebrauch genauso verwendet wie "unconditionally": Der deutsche Begriff "(un)bedingt konvergente Reihe" und der englische Begriff"(un)conditionally convergent series" sind bedeutungsgleich.

Comment: Das liegt daran, dass das deutsche Verb dingen, von dem *unbedingt* abstammt, bei weitem kein so weitgehenedes Abstraktum ist wie in den verglichenen Sprachen, sondern ein "Anstellungsverhältnis" erzeugt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Verwendung des Wortes *unbedingt* im genannten Sinne im Deutschen geht auf Immanuel Kant zurück:

Die Unterscheidung zwischen "bedingt" und "unbedingt" ist eine zentrale Denkfigur in der Erkenntnisphilosophie, Moralphilosophie und Ästhetik Immanuel Kants.

In der Erkenntnistheorie unterscheidet Kant zwischen bedingten Anschauungen und "reinen" Erkenntnissen. Bedingte Anschauungen sind bei Kant empirische Erkenntnisse. Sie sind *kontingent*, das heißt: Sie könnten auch anders sein, sie sind von einer Vorbedingung abhängig. Im Gegensatz dazu sind reine Anschauungen des Geistes in Kants Denken *notwendig*; sie sind unbedingt, das heißt voraussetzungslos, sie sind (so eine spätere nicht von Kant stammende Formulierung) "denknotwendig".

Sowohl in seiner Moralphilosophie als auch in seiner Ästhetik geht Kant von der nämlichen Unterscheidung aus. So sind etwa in seiner Moralphilosophie die bedingten moralischen Gesetze solche, die der Kultur (der "Sitte" in Kants Terminologie) oder aber dem (kontingenten) Wesen des Menschen entstammen; das unbedingte moralische Gesetz ist bei Kant ein Gesetz, das unmittelbar aus der Vernunft folgt und also notwendigerweise gilt -- er nennt dieses moralische Gesetz auch den "kategorischen Imperativ".

Bei Kant schwingt in dieser Unterscheidung immer eine gewisse Wertung mit. Er interessiert sich stärker für das Unbedingte als für das Bedingte. Dieses überlässt er den Wissenschaften, die Arbeit am Unbedingten ist seiner Auffassung nach die Aufgabe der Philosophie.

Der Umstand, dass die Denkfigur des "infiniten Regresses" philosophisch problematisch ist, ist nicht zuerst von Kant entdeckt worden -- Sie findet sich etwa schon in Aristoteles' Behandlung des Problems des "Ersten Bewegers";  Kant macht das Regress-Problem aber zu einem Kernelement seiner Philosophie. Für die deutsche Sprache ist es an dieser Stelle nur relevant, dass Kant die Terminologie von "bedingt" vs. "unbedingt" einführt.

Von den Philosophen des Deutschen Idealismus (Hegel, Fichte, Schelling), von Schopenhauer und von den Jenaer Frühromantikern wird diese Denkfigur inklusive der Kantschen Terminoloigie breit rezipiert und verbreitet und so in der deutschen Sprache etabliert.

Hier sei nur ein späteres (recht willkürlich herausgegriffenes) Beispiel für diese Rezeption genannt: In dem Prolog *Höllenfahrt* seiner Romantetralogie *Joseph und seine Brüder* entwickelt Thomas Mann die Vorstellung, dass es in der Historie immer nur bedingte Anfänge gibt:

> daß jeder einen Vater hat und daß kein Ding zuerst und von selber ist,
> Ursache seiner selbst, sondern ein jedes gezeugt ist und rückwärts weist
> [...]

[Thomas Mann: *Joseph und seine Brüder*. Vier Romane in einem Band, S. Fischer, Frankfurt am Main 2007, S.18]

Damit führt Mann die Kantsche Denkfigur in die Geschichtsphilosophie ein, und benutzt sie, um eine romantische Poetologie, eine romantisierende Lehre des Erzählens zu entfalten:

> [...] zurück zum Anfang, zur Entstehung der Welt, der Himmel und des irdischen Alls
> aus Tohu und Bohu durch das Wort, das frei über der Urflut schwebte und Gott
> war. Aber war nicht auch dies nur ein bedingter, besonderer Anfang der Dinge?
> Wesen hatten damals dem Schöpfer bewundernd und auch verwundert zugeschaut:
> Söhne Gottes, Gestirnengel, von denen Joseph manche merkwürdige und selbst
> lustige Geschichte kannte, und widrige Dämonen. Sie mußten aus einem
> vergangenen Welt-Äon entstammen, das einst zu Tohu- und Bohu-Rohstoff geworden
> war bei seinem Altersuntergange -- und war nun dieses das Allererste gewesen?

[ebd., S. 19]

Von Kant eingeführt, nimmt das Begriffspaar *unbedingt* / *bedingt* die Stellung ein, die in anderen Sprachen typischwerweise durch Wortpaare ausgefüllt wird, die ihre wörtliche Entsprechung im Deutschen in "absolut" / "relativ" finden.

Dies lässt sich in google ngram nachvollziehen, wo das Wort ab 1781 (dem
Jahr des Erscheinens der Kritik der Reinen Vernunft) einen deutlichen und
stetigen Konjunkturzuwachs verzeichnet:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unbedingt&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: Nicht jeder philosophische Gedanke ist von Kant. Philipp Jakob Spener: [Theologische Bedencken](https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/spener_bedencken03_1702?p=75), 1702, verwendet mit lateinischer Übersetzung _unbedingt, certituda absoluta_ und _bedingt, certituda conditionata_ als Figuren des Glaubens. Noch näher an Kant ist Johann Heinrich Lambert: [Neues Organon](https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/lambert_organon01_1764?p=106), 1764: "Solche Sätze nennt man bedingt, oder hypothetisch. Sie sind den unbedingten, ausdrücklichen oder cathegorischen entgegengesetzt."

Comment: Auch die [DWDS-Verlaufskurve](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=dta%2Bdwds&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A1999&q1=unbedingt) zeigt einen kontinuierlichen Anstieg der Verwendung bereits seit 1740.

Answer (score 0):

> **unbedingt** Part.adj. ‘von keiner Voraussetzung abhängig, uneingeschränkt’ aus der Rechtssprache (bedingte Verurteilung) über die Verwendung in der Fachsprache der Philosophie in die Allgemeinsprache, wo unbedingt als Adverb den Sinn ‘auf jeden Fall, unter allen Umständen’ entwickelt.

(aus „bedingen“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al., Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993), dwds.de)

Seit eines Hinweises eines weisen Lexikologen achte ich auf das Wort "unbedingt". Kurzum bemerke ich bei Grimm (DWB: *um*), was man gerade so als *false-friend* zählen kann: “halt mich umbe dina gnada (*salvum me fac propter misericordiam tuam*) 2, 15, 13;"

Der Hinweis betraf eigentlich *unbedingt*:

> (Austria, Switzerland, law) (prison sentence) unconditional, without probation

(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unbedingt)

Interessant ist daran zuerst einmal, dass *Ding* auf eine germanische Institutuion des Rechts zurückverfolgt werden kann, vgl. DRW: *bedingen* "I gerichtlich verfolgen" usw. (https://drw.hadw-bw.de/drw-cgi/zeige?index=lemmata&term=bedingen&darstellung=V).

Mit *denken* soll es verwandt sein. Die urindogermanische Etymologie ist dafür recht unbefriedigend:

> ahd. *thing* (8. Jh.), mhd. *dinc*, asächs. *thing*, mnd. mnl. *dinc*, nl. *ding*, aengl. *þing*, engl. *thing*, anord. *þing*, schwed. *ting* und (im grammatischen Wechsel) got. *þeihs* ‘Zeit’ gehen zurück auf die zur Wurzel ie. **ten-* ‘dehnen, ziehen, spannen’ gehörende Gutturalerweiterung ie. **tenk-* ‘ziehen, dehnen, spannen, Zeitspanne’. Zur gleichen Wurzel stellen sich lat. *tempus* ‘Zeitabschnitt, Zeit’ und air. *tan* ‘Zeit’.

> Es findet eine sichere außergerm. Entsprechung in lat. *tongēre*‘kennen, wissen’" und kann mit diesem auf eine Wurzelform ie. **teng-, *tong-* ‘denken, fühlen’ zurückgeführt werden.

(Pfeifer/DWDS: “Ding", "denken")

*Gutturalerweiterungen*, von denen bei **teng-* nichtmal explizit die Rede ist, dürften heute als unsicher gelten. Wiktionary folgt dem Ansatz nicht mehr. Wie ich überhaupt auf den Trichter gekommen bin, steht hier jedenfalls nicht zur Debatte.

Der springende Punkt bzgl. *um* und den Praeverben im Allgemein ist, dass *ent-* in verwandschaft zu *und* steht, und damit englisch *un-* wie in *unto* in Betracht kommt. Ein Verhältnis zu *um* ist nicht offensichtlich und beschränkt sich theoretisch auf syllabifiziiertes u in Nullstufe, das auch in *un-* / *ne*, auftritt. Die Zusammensetzung mit *-bi* bleibt fraglich: man vergleicht einerseits *bei*, *be-*, schätzt die Bildung jedoch als urindogermanisch ein, vgl. lat. *ambi*, *am-* etc. p.p; ebenso *ent-* zu *anti-*, vielleicht *ans* zu *onto*. Da einerseits Nasale in darauf folgende Konsonanten assimilieren, so sich bspw. "umbedingt" als etwaige Fehlschreibung nachweisen lässt (s. Wiktionary), andererseits Plosive aus Nasalen hervorgehen sowie in diese assmilieren (*Hummel*, engl. *humblebee, bumblebee*; schlechtes Beispiel), ist diese Betrachtung ergebnisoffen.

Im heutigen Sprachgebrauch steht *un-* fast ausschließlich für Ausschluss. In diesem Sinne bedeutet *unbedingt* bei oberflächlicher Betrachtung quasi *ohne Bedingung, egal wie*. Für die Gefängnisstrafe ist jedoch der gotische Vergleich *þeihs* ‘Zeit’ geeignet, der auf eine unbefristete Strafe hindeutet. Darunter ist im verständnis des heutigen Strafverfahrens wahrscheinlich *unverzüglich* zu verstehen und nicht *lebenslänglich*, da *bedingt* im Umkehrschluss gerade ein Aussetzen des Strafvollzugs bedeutet ("probation", en.WT). Vgl. mehrmals *unverzüglich* auch zum Vorteil des Beschuldigten §§ 141a—141c StPO (BRD), DRW noch ohne Eintrag.

Wie verhält sich all dies zum Ejngangs angeführten Zitat? Die wortwörtliche Übersetzung ist vermittelbar, *umbe* “um“ *dina* “deine“ *gnada* "Gnade". Grimm nennt dies "*causales* um", entsprechend *um Gottes Willen* (ich höre jedoch “M' Gott is' Willen[s]”).